VBA Delete Some shapes
I’m trying to delete some shapes that have macros attached and only leave combobox when copying the workbook for the end user. All my comboboxes start with Cbxxxxx.
I have the following code but it deletes the all the shapes on the sheet.
Sub Delete_buttons ()

Dim btn As Shape

For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  If btn.name <> “Cb*” Then btn.Delete
End if

Next btn 

End Sub


Your If-condition is wrong,  wildcards (*) work only when you use the like-operator. As you want to catch all shapes that don't start with Cb, the condition would be If Not btn .Name Like "Cb*" Then. If you want to be case insensitive (upper- and lowercase doesn't matter), use If Not lcase(btn .Name) Like "cb*" Then


Use Type property to identify the desired shapes

msoAutoShape (1) - AutoShape
msoFormControl (8) - Form control
msoOLEControlObject (12) - ActiveX control

Microsoft documentation:

Shape.OnAction property (Excel)


Shape.Type property (Excel)


MsoShapeType enumeration (Office)

Sub RemoveShps()
    Dim oShp As Shape
    For Each oShp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        With oShp
            If .Type = msoAutoShape And Len(.OLEFormat.Object.OnAction) > 0 Then
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

